# mysql search in large table approximately 5 Million records

Tags: mysql, search, create-table

I need to improve the SELECT query performance for search in the table. I have a table of about 5 Million rows in it. When I want to search in this table it takes a lot of time which is not acceptable. I have tried to use index but the index also can't help. please suggest me any efficient way to search through this table. It had taken my two days effort but no luck. Any help will much appreciated...

EDIT:

This the the CREATE TABLE statement I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE  marketing_emails_data ( 
   id int(11) NOT NULL, 
   name varchar(11) NOT NULL,  
   city varchar(105) DEFAULT NULL,  
   state varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT marketing_emails_data.city 
FROM marketing_emails_data 
USE INDEX (state_index) ;
```

Comment: show us the table layout and the query you want to do

Comment: CREATE TABLE  `marketing_emails_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(105) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



SELECT DISTINCT
   marketing_emails_data.city
   FROM
   marketing_emails_data
                         USE INDEX (state_index)

Comment: Create a cities table and just store the id here so you can index it.

Comment: what will be benefit of creating the cities table seperate just city name will be replaced with its id. i cant afford to update that field. for the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the distinct cities of your `marketing_emails_data` table you could create an `INDEX` on that field:

```
ALTER TABLE marketing_emails_data ADD INDEX (city);
```

Then your query should be much faster. You don't need to state the index in the query by the  way. mysql is smart enough to figure out what indexes to use in a query.

As suggested in the comments by tntu, the better way of course would be to create a city table and store only a reference to the city entry in the `marketing_emails_data` table. This will save a lot of space. This is part of database normalization.

Comment: i appreciate your help regarding this issue but will it be possible to update 5million records for city ? i think it wil be not feasible.. indeed it will save alot of space.

Comment: 5 million entries to a table is actually not very many. Mysql can easily handle many more entries

Comment: can you please suggest em any other solution to this issue. ?

Comment: did you try my first suggestion? I mean just to create an ```INDEX``` on ```city```?